# moderncv - two column entry with minipage and multicols => multicols error "ther's no line to end here"

Tags: minipage, moderncv

```
\documentclass[10cm,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\topmargin=0.0cm
\headsep=-0.5cm

\firstname{max}
\familyname{mustermann}
\title{resumee}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \section{headline}
    \hspace*{\hintscolumnwidth}%
    \begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}
        \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0pt}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \cventry{}{C\#}{basic}{}{}{} \par \cventry{}{UNIX}{basic}{}{}{} \par
            \cventry{}{vim}{basic}{}{}{} \par \cventry{}{\LaTeX}{basic}{}{}{} \par
            \cventry{}{HTML, CSS, PHP}{basic}{}{}{} \\
        \end{multicols}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

creates the following error:

```
./Lebenslauf.tex:38: LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.38        \end
           {multicols}
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

any ideas how i could fix that?

regards

Comment: Well, just remove \\ after `\cventry{}{HTML,...}` etc

Comment: @ChristianHupfer that solved it. Could you please explain that error and the solution a bit futher? i would like to understand that better.

Comment: there is no need to `\par` command

Comment: @touhami: Yes, that's right. I already wondered if they are necessary. I'll remove them from the solution

Comment: @touhami why is there no need for \par?

Comment: @toogley by the definition of `\cventry`

Comment: @touhami where can i read about that definition? i've just found the README of moderncv, but no documentation.

Comment: @touhami the source files doesn't explain that as well.

Comment: @toogley, yes a limitation of moderncv (no doc) and (surce not clear). Now in `modencvbody(i-v)(.sty)` you can find `\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%` and `\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}`

Comment: @touhami Well, i've found sth like that in one of the source files, but that doesn't make the issue more clear. The only reason i can think of, is that \par is already used in the definition. So as a consequence, \par in a \cventry is a duplicate.

Comment: @toogley if I understand, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the offending `\\` after the `\cventry{}{HTML,...}` line. 
After `\cventry` TeX is in vertical mode, so `\\` is of no use there/forbidden. Using `\leavevmode\\` would work but this enlarges the columns as well.

```
\documentclass[10cm,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.25in, left=1.25in, right=1.25in]{geometry}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.4pt}
\topmargin=0.0cm
\headsep=-0.5cm

\firstname{max}
\familyname{mustermann}
\title{resumee}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \section{headline}
    \hspace*{\hintscolumnwidth}%
    \begin{minipage}{\maincolumnwidth}
        \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0pt}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \cventry{}{C\#}{basic}{}{}{} \cventry{}{UNIX}{basic}{}{}{} 
            \cventry{}{vim}{basic}{}{}{} \par \cventry{}{\LaTeX}{basic}{}{}{} 
            \cventry{}{HTML, CSS, PHP}{basic}{}{}{} 
        \end{multicols}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]